# Error in the MYSQL procedure with Quote (Prepared Statement)

Tags: mysql

I don't know much about MYSQL and I'm trying to convert a procedure from pgsql to mysql, however it's claiming that I have this error: "You have a syntax error in your SQL next to ''. I've redone it, but it continues giving this error, can anyone help?

This is the MYSQL procedure that is giving an error:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE cadastro_cliente(IN _cpf VARCHAR(20), IN _nome TEXT, IN _data_nasc DATE,
            IN _telefone VARCHAR(20), IN _email VARCHAR(100), IN _senha VARCHAR(12),
            IN _endereco TEXT, IN _cep VARCHAR(20), IN _cidade VARCHAR(50), IN _estado CHAR(2), IN _caminho_foto_perfil TEXT)
BEGIN    
SET @query = CONCAT("INSERT INTO cliente (cpf, nome, data_nasc,telefone, email, senha, endereco, cep, cidade, estado, caminho_foto_perfil) VALUES (", QUOTE(_cpf),",", QUOTE(_nome),",", QUOTE(_data_nasc),",", QUOTE(_telefone),",", QUOTE(_email),",", QUOTE(_senha),",", QUOTE(_endereco),",", QUOTE(_cep),",", QUOTE(_cidade),",", QUOTE(_estado),",", QUOTE(_esta_caminho_foto_perfildo),");");
PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
SET @query = NULL;
END;
```

This is the PGSQL procedure I want to do:

```
CREATE or replace FUNCTION 
cadastro_cliente(_cpf VARCHAR, _nome VARCHAR, _data_nasc DATE,
                _telefone VARCHAR, _email VARCHAR, _senha VARCHAR,
                _endereco TEXT, _cep VARCHAR, _estado CHAR)
RETURNS void AS $$

DECLARE
    dt_cadastro DATE := (SELECT now()::timestamp(0));
    last_login DATE := (SELECT now()::timestamp(0));
    update_reg DATE := (SELECT now()::timestamp(0));

BEGIN
    EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO cliente VALUES (quote_ident($1),
    quote_ident($2),$9 ,quote_ident($3),
    quote_ident($4),quote_ident($5),$10 ,
    $11 ,$12 ,quote_ident($6),
    quote_ident($7), quote_ident($8));' 
    USING _cpf, _nome, _telefone, _email, _senha,
    _endereco, _cep, _estado, _data_nasc, dt_cadastro, 
    last_login, update_reg;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: For example, it could help to reduce the parameters step by step to spot a typo

Comment: Your quotes are all wrong on the concat line. Check your double and single quotes.

Comment: I'm sure the quotes are wrong, but it might sound silly, I can't find where. I already redid it, I changed the double quotes to single, but it still gives the same error ( #1064 - You have a syntax error in your SQL next to '' in line 5). Could someone show me the correct way to make me learn? Even because I have a few more procedures to transform.

Answer (score 1):

No need to use prepared statements. You can create the procedure like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE cadastro_cliente(
_cpf VARCHAR(20), 
_nome TEXT, 
_data_nasc DATE,
_telefone VARCHAR(20), 
_email VARCHAR(100), 
_senha VARCHAR(12),
_endereco TEXT, 
_cep VARCHAR(20), 
_cidade VARCHAR(50), 
_estado CHAR(2), 
_caminho_foto_perfil TEXT
)
BEGIN    

INSERT INTO cliente (cpf, nome, data_nasc,telefone, email, senha, endereco, cep, cidade, estado, caminho_foto_perfil) 
VALUES (_cpf, _nome, _data_nasc, _telefone, _email, _senha, _endereco, _cep, _cidade, _estado, _caminho_foto_perfil);

END
```

Comment: That way I can protect against SQL injection too?

Comment: That depends also on your code calling the procedure. Try avoiding dynamic SQL in your procedures though.